# Check if array contains element

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filtering

I have a class called *Person*:

```
class Person{

  let name: String?
  let areas: [Area]
}
```

And *Area* consisting of the following:

```
class Area{
  let id: String
  let name: String
}
```

I've created a "people" array and what I want to do is check the "people" array if area.name = "Brooklyn". If it doesn't remove that person from the "people" array.

Here is what I have tried but it doesn't work:

```
var people = [Person]()

for s in people{

  for a in s.preferredArea{

    if a.areaName != "Brooklyn"{

       let index = people.indexOf(s)
       people.removeAtIndex(index!)
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone point me into the right direction please?

Comment: You can't mutate the array that you are iterating.  You can build a new array and then assign that to your property/return it from a function when you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `indexOf`, you'll have to make `Person` conforming the protocol `Equatable`:

```
class Person: Equatable {

    let name: String
    var area: [Area]

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.area = []
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name &&
           lhs.area == rhs.area      // You'll have to make Area equatable too
}
```

Having this done, your code just works fine. If you don't want to use this method, you can use:

```
people.enumerate().forEach {
    if !$0.1.area.contains({ $0.name == "Brooklyn" }) {
        people.removeAtIndex($0.0)
    }
}
```

Or if you can use filter to create a new array:

```
var newPeople = people.filter { $0.area.contains { $0.name == "Brooklyn" } }
```